# javafx swipe detection misplaced from item it was added to?

Tags: javafx, swipe

i have created an image viewer with tree structure to its left. I have added a borderpane -> SPlit pane at centre-> treeview on left and imageview on right. finally i have added swipe events using scenebuilder to the imageview. the swipe gets detected in the encircled area only rather than anywhere in imageview.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ybb.jpg)

Comment: Hard to tell where the problem is without providing us with some code, mate. How are you handling the drag-n-drop? Have you been following a tutorial, if so, which one?

Comment: [mcve] please..